# C error: expected expression before â.â token

Tags: c

I keep getting this error when I try to compile my code :

```
cc -Wall -Werror -g -c -o lwp.o lwp.c
lwp.c: In function ânew_intel_stackâ:
lwp.c:120: error: expected expression before â.â token
lwp.c:122: error: expected expression before â.â token
lwp.c:124: error: expected expression before â.â token
lwp.c:126: error: expected expression before â.â token
lwp.c:130: error: expected expression before â.â token
lwp.c:132: error: expected expression before â.â token
lwp.c:134: error: expected expression before â.â token
lwp.c:136: error: expected expression before â.â token
lwp.c:138: error: expected expression before â.â token
lwp.c:140: error: expected expression before â.â token
lwp.c:142: error: expected expression before â.â token
make: *** [lwp.o] Error 1
```

The function it is referring to is here :

```
/* make ourselves a nice intuitive "push()" macro */
#define push(sp,val) (*(..sp)=(unsigned)(val))

unsigned long *new_intel_stack(unsigned long *sp,lwpfun func, void *arg) {
    unsigned long *ebp;
    push(sp,arg); /* argument */
    push(sp,lwp_exit); /* for lwp return purposes */
    push(sp,func); /* function's return address */
    push(sp,0x1abcdef1); /* bogus "saved" base pointer */
    ebp=sp; /* remember sp from this point for later */
    push(sp,0x6c6f7453); /* push initial eax, ebx, ecx, edx, esi and edi -- bogus */
    push(sp,0x66206e65);
    push(sp,0x206d6f72);
    push(sp,0x746e6957);
    push(sp,0x32207265);
    push(sp,0x21363030);
    push(sp,ebp); /* push initial edp */
    return sp;
}
```

I don't really know why I am getting this error. Any ideas?

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is caused by the `..` sequence inside your macro.

What is `..` supposed to mean in the macro definition?

```
(*(..sp)=(unsigned)(val))
```

There's nothing in C language that would match your usage of that `..`. C has `.` operator, but it can't be used the way it is used inside your macro.

Comment: The {..} sequence was actually supposed to be a {--}. Thanks!

Comment: @cYrus @AndreyT My comment was posted before the answer was edited, and mentioned the `..` before `sp`. All clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean

```
#define push(sp,val) (*(--sp)=(unsigned)(val))
```

??